# Has and belongs to many vs. has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

This isn't another should I use HABTM or HMT question. Honest. That said, I *am* going to ask whether people would use HABTM or HMT in the following situation.

- I have a model "Book".
- I want to add a model "Author".  An Author has_many Books.  A Book has_many Authors.
- I want to add a model "Topic".  A Topic has_many Books.  A Book has_many Topics.

I already know the difference between the two assocations, I know about join tables, and I know (generally) the benefits to each association system.

Clearly I can set up two HABTM relationships here.

However, it struck me that I could also be witty and put my foreign_ids in the "Books" model table by declaring Authors and Topics as "has_many :authors/topics, :through => :books".

My question is whether people think this is an over-abstraction of the database structure, given that the primary relationship is between BOOKS and AUTHORS, and BOOKS and TOPICS, and is not the direct relationship between AUTHOR and TOPIC?

Put another way, it seemed that while I get to do away with two (extra) join tables and use the more flexible HMT relationship, I might be diluting the point of my database, which was to store BOOKS, which then link to AUTHORS and TOPICS.

I thought this was a relatively interesting question.

Also, all the other examples on the Internet I could find of the use of HMT used the "through" table as a relatively insignificant portion of the database.  For example
- using it as a "through" table to store grades of STUDENTS who took TESTS;
- to store info about magazine subscriptions of SUBSCRIBERS who subscribed to MAGAZINES.

I've never seen an example where the "through" table stores primary information.  It seems to be more for storing ancillary information about the two main tables that it joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot do what I wanted to do; that is, put the join table in BOOKS.  Why not?  Because if I make BOOKS the join table, each book will have exactly one "author_id" and exactly one "topic_id".  Since I want to be able to have multiple authors per book and multiple topics per book, I will have nowhere to place those relationships.

The reason why this doesn't work is that HMT allows you to create a model that can store additional information about *a relationship*.  In my situation, that would be the relationship between *a specific* author and *a specific* topic.

A book is not an instance of this relationship.

Instead I'll need to HMT books to authors, and books to topics.  *THEN* if I wanted to store additional information about the relationship between an author and a book, I'd have a model to store it in.  That additional information might be:

- the age of the author when he wrote it
- the amount the author was paid to write it
- the date the author finished writing the book

and in each case you can see the information stored in the HMT model is particular to both the author and the book being joined.  (So if I had multiple authors, the information about author #2<->book would be stored in a separate HMT model.)

As @dasil003 pointed out, you could kludge around this and try to store multiple relationships in one field, but then you'd probably not be able to join properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "belongs_to_many: through Books", but both habtm and hmt use a join table.  If you have a many-to-many relationship there's no getting away from it.  I don't understand how you plan to store multiple authors or topics on books table.  If you combine the values in a single field you won't be able to join the authors or topics.  If you have a fixed maximum you could add an association field for each one, but that seems kludgy in most cases.

As for an example of primary data on a hmt relationship.  Imagine that you were assuming that each topic had a specific chapter in a book (contrived I know, but it fits your model).  The topic might be a different chapter in each book.  In that case you would need to add the chapter field to the join table and use hmt.

Comment: Yes, I meant "has many :through =>".  Also, yes, both associations have a join table, but I am basically wondering if it's a smart idea to use a primary table (in this case the BOOKS table) to try to act as the join table for AUTHORS and TOPICS.  Does that clarify?  To answer your question, I would think the BOOKS table would contain author_id and topics_id, and so each book could refer to authors and topics that way.  I'm just wondering if I'm overusing HMT by cluttering up my BOOKS table (using it as the join)?

Comment: You can definitely do that. HMT doesn't check the content of the table, so as long as you have the right ids in there you can go nuts. All the HMT (and `:polymorphic` for that matter) does is set up the methods, so as long as you're careful about what you're putting where, you can get away with it. Even within the documentation, if an HMT is merely an HABTM that allows extra attributes (by being a discrete model), this can be reversed such that any model comprised of "extra attributes" can be a join model. Just add IDs!

Comment: @Eric, but if I put the join table in the BOOK table, don't I run into trouble if (for ex.) I have two authors who wrote that book?  My Book model would have a unique entry for Book #1, given.  It would then need to link to Author #1 _AS WELL AS_ Author #2, and where would the second entry go?  Wouldn't the Book table entry simply have a single author_id integer key and a single topic_id key?

In a HABTM you just repeat keys: i.e. 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 (for book #1 having three authors).  But in my case my BOOKS table is already populated with entries, each representing a given book.  ??

Comment: ... and I think what I just said in my comment to @Eric might have been what you were saying in your response, which I didn't quite clue in to yesterday. ... I think I'm stuck having to do two separate HBT associations here.  My books are unique, so I can't use the BOOKS table to store info about AUTHOR-TOPIC relationship because the extra fields are not unique to _that_ relationship.  They are unique to the book itself.

(Unless author_id and topic_id in BOOKS table can be arrays, but I've never looked into that and it would probably stretch the purpose of HMT.)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the vast majority of Rails people prefers has_many through. To tell you the truth, i think that HABTM will be removed from Rails in the versions to come. Using through is more explicit and less error prone and i strongly suggest that you use that instead. Especially, if this is the first time you create join tables in Rails.

Now, using a foreign id on books is not a good idea. You would be trying to make a many to many association using two tables and that is a very bad relational databases thing to do :) Instead, with many to many associations, stick to using has many through, that should be just fine.

(btw, belongs_to_many does not exist, you would need a third model to do that)

Comment: Yes sorry, meant "has many :through =>".  I should say I'm leaning towards just doing a regular HMT between BOOKS and AUTHORS, and one between BOOKS and TOPICS for future upgradability and in case I ever end up needing to add information about those relationships.  But then I got curious whether I could put both joins in the BOOKS table, or whether I was getting too witty by half ...

Comment: yeap, two HTM is the best way to go for sure :)